# After Yosemite, the volume adjustment doesn't make noise?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, macos

I tried to fix it in system preference...but when I did, it made a weird ticking noise rather that the noise it used to. How do I get this to go back to normal?

Answer (score 1):

This bugged me as well.  You can change it by modifying the sound it plays.  Open Terminal.app and execute the following commands.

First navigate to the following directory:

```
cd /System/Library/LoginPlugins/BezelServices.loginPlugin/Contents/Resources
```

Then make a backup of the Yosemite sound, if you want to.

```
sudo cp volume.aiff volume_backup.aiff
```

Move the old sound file from Mavericks (or anything you want), found in the link below and rename it to volume.aiff.  (If you use the link below it will already be named volume.aiff afer you extract it)

```
sudo cp "~/Desktop/mysound.aiff" volume.aiff
```

Change **~/Desktop/mysound.aiff** from above command to the path to the new sound file you want to use.

Restart for it to take effect.

Original sources I used below:

[MacWorld Change Volume Sound](http://www.macworld.com/article/1057197/beepchange.html)

[Macrumors forum with original sound.aiff](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1767911)

Comment: Started to look for this earlier and got sidetracked. Nice find.